# update multiple keys in array representing progressbars in different speeds

Tags: php, arrays, loops, arraylist

i have 9 progress bars. generated from an array like this:

```
$progress = "100-30-0-0-0-0-0-0-0";
$array= explode("-", $progress );
```

I need to update the progress bar in different speeds. This is how I do it now:

```
if($array[0] >= 100){  $array[0]  = 100; }else{ $array[0] = $array[0] + rand(3,8); }    
if($array[0] >= 75){if($array[1] >= 100 ){ $array[1] = 100; }else{ $array[1] = $array[1] + rand(2,7); }} 
if($array[1] >= 75){if($array[2] >= 100 ){ $array[2] = 100; }else{ $array[2] = $array[2] + rand(2,5); }} 
if($array[2] >= 75){if($array[3] >= 100 ){ $array[3] = 100; }else{ $array[3] = $array[3] + rand(1,4); }} 
if($array[3] >= 75){if($array[4] >= 100 ){ $array[4] = 100; }else{ $array[4] = $array[4] + rand(1,3); }} 
if($array[4] >= 75){if($array[5] >= 100 ){ $array[5] = 100; }else{ $array[5] = $array[5] + rand(1,3); }} 
if($array[5] >= 75){if($array[6] >= 100 ){ $array[6] = 100; }else{ $array[6] = $array[6] + rand(1,2); }} 
if($array[6] >= 75){if($array[7] >= 100 ){ $array[7] = 100; }else{ $array[7] = $array[7] + rand(0,2); }} 
if($array[7] >= 75){if($array[8] >= 100 ){ $array[8] = 100; }else{ $array[8] = $array[8] + rand(0,1); }} 

if($array[0] > 100 ){ $array[0] = 100;}
if($array[1] > 100 ){ $array[1] = 100;}
if($array[2] > 100 ){ $array[2] = 100;}
if($array[3] > 100 ){ $array[3] = 100;}
if($array[4] > 100 ){ $array[4] = 100;}
if($array[5] > 100 ){ $array[5] = 100;}
if($array[6] > 100 ){ $array[6] = 100;}
if($array[7] > 100 ){ $array[7] = 100;}
if($array[8] > 100 ){ $array[8] = 100;}

$progress  = implode("-", $array);
```

This updates the first progress bar up to 75 %, 3 to 8% a the time before the next progress bar start increasing, in slower and slower rate.

Now I need a loop to update an endless amount of progress bars in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using way too many if statement, making the whole thing manual. You should be doing it in a loop.

Here's an example, that uses your arguments to rand (how are they generated? I've just hardcoded your ones, and default to rand(0,1) if its beyond 9.

This loops through the progress values and if one is less than 100 applies the random addition, never more than 100, and then breaks.

There's a next link I used for testing.

```
<?php
$progress = isset($_GET['progress'])?$_GET['progress']:"0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0";
$array= explode("-", $progress ); 

$randArgs = array(
    array(3,8),
    array(2,7),
    array(2,5),
    array(1,4),
    array(1,3),
    array(1,3),
    array(1,2),
    array(0,2),
    array(0,1),
);

foreach($array as $key => $progressbar) {
    if ($progressbar < 100) {
        $limits = isset($randArgs[$key]) ? $randArgs[$key] : array(0,1);
        $nextValue = $progressbar + rand($limits[0], $limits[1]);
        $array[$key] = $nextValue > 100 ? 100 : $nextValue;
        break;
    }
}

$progress  = implode("-", $array);

var_dump($progress);

?>
<a href="?progress=<?php echo $progress?>">Next</a>
```